# How to implement placeholder in a php file for moodle plugin?

Tags: php, css, moodle

Hello im new to moodle plugin development and I need to make the "Enter course schedule here..." in the third line disappear when I enter text. If im not mistake it is called placeholder but i dont know how to implement to.

[Php code in my own moodle plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvY0Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$mform->addElement('text', 'sched_code', 'Schedule Code', ['placeholder' => 'Enter course schedule here...']);
```

Although, you will want to use get_string() for both bits of text that are being output, rather than hard-coding them like that, so that they can be translated / customised as required.